# Regex for PHP preg_replace to find numbers between tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I know it's naive question, but regex is always confusing for me.

I want to replace numbers in a string if they are between a tag, here parenthesis.

```
$str = " Some text 11 have number 12 (11,12,13)";

$array = array( 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve', 13 => 'thirteen');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
$str = preg_replace( 'regex to match $key', $value, $str);
}
```

The result should be

```
$str = " Some text 11 have number 12 (eleven,twelve,thirteen)";
```

I am struggling with regex pattern to match number which should be within parenthesis. Inside the parenthesis is only numbers and `,`.

Comment: Come on, I don't think that `'regex to match $key'` is your best attempt so far. You're expected to get help with your code, not get it all done for you.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález what is missing in the code except regex pattern?!?!?

Comment: Alright, I'll give you a couple of tips to get started: 1) The first argument to `preg_replace()` has to include both the expression and the modifiers so you have to use delimiters around, e.g. `'/foo/'` 2) The function returns the replaced string and doesn't modify the original value so you have to store the returned value somewhere. -- You can find some usage examples in the PHP manual http://php.net/preg_replace

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/xdsnjK, let me know if you wish me to post with explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I appreciate if you post it as an answer, as it is the only solution which perfectly works for all cases. Then, I can accept it, which can be helpful for others too. Thanks, it was an incredible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a regex that finds all consecutive numbers (digit chunks) separated with a comma after an opening `(`. Then, the matches can be passed to a `preg_replace_callback` and if the corresponding key is present in the array, replace it with the corresponding value, else, just put the match back.

Here is the regex:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\(),?\K\d+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH1bT6/1)

**Details:**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\()` - Matches either the position of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or a `(` symbol
- `,?` - an optional (1 or 0) comma
- `\K` - an operator discarding all the text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits (the only text we have in the match returned).

And here is the [PHP code](http://ideone.com/xdsnjK):

```
$re = '/(?:\G(?!\A)|\(),?\K\d+/'; 
$str = "Some text 11 have number 12 (9,11,12,13)"; 
$array = array( 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve', 13 => 'thirteen');

echo $result = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($m) use ($array) {
    return !empty($array[$m[0]]) ? $array[$m[0]] : $m[0];
}, $str) . PHP_EOL;
```

The result is `Some text 11 have number 12 (9,eleven,twelve,thirteen)` as `9` is missing in the `$array`.

Comment: This is incredibly subtle!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$str = " Some text 11 have number 12 (11,12,13)";
$array = array( 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve', 13 => 'thirteen');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $str = preg_replace('/(\(|,)' . $key . '(\)|,)/', "$1" . $value . "$2", $str);
}
```

And when you `var_dump($str)`:

```
string(53) " Some text 11 have number 12 (eleven,twelve,thirteen)"
```

Comment: Thanks for explicit code, but it does not limit the search to numbers between `(` and  `,`. If you add number 1 to the array, it will replace 1 out of 11. Regex must dictates that the previous character is `(` or `,` and next character is `)` or `,`.

Comment: There you go @All, I've updated my regex and it should work now even if you add lower numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `preg_replace_callback`. Then you can use `\(([\d\h,]+)\)` which checks for numbers, horizontal spaces, or commas inside `()` and captures all found values. The function then uses `str_replace` to replace them.

```
$string = " Some text 11 have number 12 (11,12,13)";
$array = array( 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve', 13 => 'thirteen');
echo preg_replace_callback('/\(([\d\h,]+)\)/', function ($matches) use ($array) {
     return str_replace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), $matches[1]);
}, $string);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/589888

Comment: I think there is just one drawback: you need to account for a missing array key. Although I also think you can use just 1 regex to match each number in the `(...)`  separately, so as not to use `str_replace`.

Comment: You mean like `, 13 => 'thirteen', 14, 15 => 'fifteen'`? Yea, I presumed the array always has paired number with word.

Comment: I meant [`(?:\G(?!\A)|\(),?\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/aH1bT6/1) and checking the presence of the key with `empty($array[$m[0]])`.

Comment: Ok, had to add an answer, see below.

Comment: Oh, yea, that's a lot cleaner.